# IOS 13.1.3 does not have a sync over wifi button on my phone, what do i do

Tags: iphone

I have never tried to sync over wifi, but I have followed online directions, problem is, under my general settings there is no option to sync over wifi. It seems the button should be located next to VPN but its not there, has it moved? I have searched all through my phone settings, I cant find it

Comment: Are you trying to sync it to your Mac?

Comment: no, windows 10, but the issue isn't on my pc, as far as I know, the options doesn't appear on my phone, it says it should be a button next to vpn option under settings, but there is no option to sync over wifi in 13.1.3, but it does appear in my itunes

Answer (score 1):

This button was removed in iOS 13 for no apparent reason. Since then, this button is missing so you have to wait for a fix for this in a new update.

Comment: thank you very much for this info, at least it wasn't moved and we weren't notified, thanks again